# Initializing an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

What is wrong with the following code?

```
<?php
$login_user[] = array ();
array_push($login_user, "cat" );
array_push($login_user, "dog" );
print_r($login_user);
?>
```

I expected to get an array of ("cat", dog"). Instead I unexpectedly got an empty array as the first element:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => cat [2] => dog )
```

Comment: `$login_user[]  = array ();` Remove the `[]` part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code

```
$login_user[] = array();
```

**You are pushing** to `$login_user` an empty `array()`, so the first element of $login_user will be an empty array. View [PHP Array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

By the official [documentation of PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you can see that there are **two ways** to initialize an empty array

- By using `$my_new_array = array();`
- By using other equivalent short notation `$my_new_array = [];` as of PHP >= 5.4

So your code should be something like this

```
$login_user = []; //or $login_user = array()

array_push($login_user, "cat" ); //or $login_user[] = "cat"
array_push($login_user, "dog" ); //or $login_user[] = "dog"

print_r($login_user);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

The `[]` means `$login_user` is now an array and you are creating an array as its first element. Get rid of the `[]` to resolve this issue.

```
<?php
    $login_user = array();
    array_push($login_user, "cat" );
    array_push($login_user, "dog" );
    print_r($login_user);
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/436342)